# Proper way to display wait dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have WaitDialog with Marquee style ProgressBar.

1. Is this a proper way to display it ?

   ```
       var wd = new WaitDialog();
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
           LongRunningMethod();
           wd.Close();
       });
       wd.ShowDialog();
   ```
2. Please recommend a proper way to report progress from a Task for non Marquee ProgressBar.

Comment: You may find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38623334/3110834) useful.

Answer (score 5):

What I think you're looking for is a way to run your long running method and display a progress dialog without locking up the UI. You also need to watch out for cross-threading issues by accessing your UI from a different thread.

What I would suggest is to pattern it this way which will keep your application responsive while the task is running:

```
    var wd = new WaitDialog();
    wd.Show(); // Show() instead of ShowDialog() to avoid blocking
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongRunningMethod());
    // use .ContinueWith to avoid blocking
    task.ContinueWith(result => wd.Invoke((Action)(() => wd.Close())));
```

You show your progress dialog -- whether it has a marquee or not is of no consequence -- and then you spin up your `LongRunningMethod` on its own task.  Use the `.ContinueWith` method to close your dialog when the task has completed and to also avoid blocking the rest of your program.